# Django website very slow using Apache and mod_wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

so today I tried to host a website using django on a Ubuntu vServer using Apache and mod_wsgi.
First I tested it with a blank django project, and everything worked perfectly, but as soon as I put my django project on the server and set Apache up to run with that, the performance of the server dropped a lot. When accessing the website using apache, the response time is about 10 seconds per page, in contrast do about 100ms when using the django dev server.
I should mentiona that the server has 8GB of ram and a quad-code cpu. When running htop not even 1% CPU usage and about 50MB of ram are used. When im accessing the website, the cpu usage gets really high for a second, just before the website is loaded and then goes back to <1%

Does any body have any tips on what could be the cause of that? I've read that there may be problems with the some mpm workers, but i didnt really find the files i would need to adjust on my server.

The apache server config looks like this(paths changed):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
. . .

Alias /static /home/sammy/myproject/static
<Directory /home/sammy/myproject/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/sammy/myproject/myproject>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>

WSGIDaemonProcess myproject python-home=/home/sammy/myproject/myprojectenv python-path=/home/sammy/myproject
WSGIProcessGroup myproject
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/sammy/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py
```

In my error.log file, i also get a lot of these errors:

```
Mon Nov 23 11:20:12.551962 2020] [wsgi:alert] [pid 26252:tid 140403038272448] (11)Resource temporarily unavailable: mod_wsgi (pid=26252): Couldn't create worker thread 2 in daemon process 'myproject'.
```

and

> Exception ignored in: <bound method BaseEventLoop.**del** of <_UnixSelectorEventLoop running=False closed=False debug=False>>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 526, in **del**
> NameError: name 'ResourceWarning' is not defined

Also, here is the "apachectl status" when idling: https://pastebin.com/D40pRNSY

Comment: Do you have enough RAM? Have you tried Nginx instead of Apache. I know it's not an answer but you should give more info. Such CPU load, free RAM, mb iotop.

Comment: No, havent tried nginx yet, added load info to the question, load is very low